# Linq to SQL to aggregate data by week

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-sql

I have a table with columns of Date, Buy, Sell, InStock, and a table with date and corresponding week of the year (please see below for the tables). And want to aggregate the columns of Buy and Sell by Week.

There is some function in LINQ to SQL that aggregates data by month or by year, but I could not find any function to aggregate data by week.

Could someone help me with LINQ to SQL query to get the data using the two tables? Any suggestion is appreciated.

The first two tables are what I have, and I want to get the third table by joining the two tables using LINQ query.

---

Sales Table

Date               Buy                   Sell                 InStock
1/1/2017            5                     2                     123
1/2/2017            4                     4                     123
1/3/2017            3                     7                     119
1/4/2017            4                     2                     121
1/5/2017            3                     2                     122
1/6/2017            5                     2                     125
1/7/2017            3                    2                      126
1/8/2017            7                     5                     128
1/9/2017            5                     8                     125
1/10/2017           2                     2                     125
1/11/2017           1                     2                     124
1/12/2017           5                     2                     127
1/13/2017           2                     2                     127
1/14/2017           3                     2                     128
1/15/2017           4                     3                     129
1/16/2017           5                     2                     132
…                                                …                        …                      …

---

DateToWeek Table

Date                  WeekOfTheYear
1/1/2017                          1
1/2/2017                          1
1/3/2017                          1
1/4/2017                          1
1/5/2017                          1
1/6/2017                          1
1/7/2017                          1
1/8/2017                          2
1/9/2017                          2
1/10/2017                         2
1/11/2017                         2
1/12/2017                         2
1/13/2017                         2
1/14/2017                         2
1/15/2017                         3
1/16/2017                         3
1/17/2017                         3
1/18/2017                         3
1/19/2017                         3
…                                    …

### Table I want to get:

Date      Week       Buy        Sell         InStock
1/1/2017        1              27                     21                    123
1/8/2017        2              25                     25                     128
1/15/2017       3              22                     28                    122
…               …              …                       …

Comment: if performance is not much cared, suggest fetch entire table to memory then    query by linq.

Comment: No, the memory is not an issue. I am not sure how to join the two tables to get the data I need.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the query like that. I can not test...

```
from st in db.SalesTable 
join w in db.DateToWeek on st.DateBuy equals w.Date
group new {st, w} by new {w.Date, w.WeekOfTheYear} into gr
select new 
{
    Date = gr.Key.Date,
    Week = gr.Key.WeekOfTheYear,
    Buy = gr.Sum(x=>x.Buy),
    Sell = gr.Sum(x => x.Sell),
    InStock = gr.Sum(x=>x.Instock)
}
```

Comment: TriV, the query groups buy and sell by date and WeekOfYear, and it still has data by day not aggregated by week.

Answer (score 0):

```
            var query = (from c in
            (from st in db.SalesTable 
                  join w in db.DateToWeek on st.DateBuy equals w.Date
                  group new {st, w} by new {w.WeekOfTheYear} into gr
                     select new 
                               {
                               Week = gr.Key.WeekOfTheYear,
                               Buy = gr.Sum(x=>x.Buy),
                               Sell = gr.Sum(x => x.Sell),
                               InStock = gr.Sum(x=>x.Instock)
                             })
                     group c by c.Week into gr2
                     select new
                     {
                         Date = gr2.Min(x=>x.Date),
                         Buy = gr2.Sum(x => x.Buy),
                         Sell = gr2.Sum(x => x.Sell),
                     }

            ).OrderBy(x => x.Date);
```